# Problems to Install Symfony on my ovh webspace :/

Tags: symfony

I try to install symfony only after i enter my things like database and smtp data then comes an error:

```
In Process.php line 143:

  [TypeError]
  Symfony\Component\Process\Process::__construct(): Argument #1 ($command) mu
  st be of type array, string given, called in /home/esbdkig/test.pluginstube
  .net/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Com
  poser/ScriptHandler.php on line 342


Exception trace:
  at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:143
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->__construct() at /home/esbdkig/test.pluginstube.net/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:342
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::executeBuildBootstrap() at /home/esbdkig/test.pluginstube.net/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:82
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:386
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:246
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:107
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:226
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:123
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:374
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/CreateProjectCommand.php:263
 Composer\Command\CreateProjectCommand->installProject() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/CreateProjectCommand.php:171
 Composer\Command\CreateProjectCommand->execute() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:298
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1028
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:299
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:375
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:139
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///home/esbdkig/composer.phar/bin/composer:88
 require() at /home/esbdkig/composer.phar:29

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]
```

[Console IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcBHj.png)

Can someone please help me

I have tried to install it as it is described here [https://docs.ovh.com/de/hosting/composer-installieren-hosting/](https://docs.ovh.com/de/hosting/composer-installieren-hosting/)](https://docs.ovh.com/de/hosting/composer-installieren-hosting/%5D(https://docs.ovh.com/de/hosting/composer-installieren-hosting/))

Comment: This looks kinda old, what version of php are you using? Can you share your composer.json file?

Comment: I use this PHP version: PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun  2 2022 17:00:00) (NTS)

and the composer.json like that: https://hastebin.com/olixogeyox.json

Comment: Is this an existing project? Symfony 2.7 is very old. Not sure it is compatible with PHP 8. For supported Symfony versions see https://symfony.com/releases.

Comment: I have bought a new linux rootserver and now it works :)